# Countif or counta google Spreadsheets to count word appearances

Tags: google-sheets, countif, text-classification

I want to count how many times specific words show up (per line) in my google spreadsheet.  
My spreadsheet looks like this (while ? is the area where i want to have my counted results): 
table 1 
 **|comments|mentions delivery|mentions price|mentions service|** 
|fast delivery, very good support|?|?|?| 
|price for quality was too high. package was damaged|?|?|?| 
|E-mail support was fast and helpful|0?|?|?|

table 2 (all words that table 1 comments should be compared to): 
**|mentions delivery|mentions price|mentions service|** 
|delivery|price|support| 
|shipping|pricey|service| 
|box|-|call|

after counting how many of my words from table 2 show up in the comments of table 1 table 1 should look like this: 
**|comments|mentions delivery|mentions price|mentions service|** 
|fast delivery, very good support|1|0|1| 
|price for quality was too high. package was damaged|1|1|0| 
|E-mail support was fast and helpful|0|0|1| 
 
I tried using the countif function which i could not get to work and are now using counta, which works like expected (without using table 2), but I want to have the formular adjust automatically when I add more words in table 2:

`=COUNTA(Filter(Split(D2," "),"delivery")) + COUNTA(Filter(Split(D2," "),"shipping"))`
 
Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that F2 contains a comment while column A lists the words related to delivery. The following formula computes the number of words in column A that appear in the comment. It requires word boundaries, so that "caprice" is not mistaken for "price", but allows some plural forms, so that "price" is recognized in "prices" and "box" in "boxes".

```
=sum(arrayformula(n(regexmatch(F2, "\b" & filter(A2:A, len(A2:A)) & "e?s?\b"))))
```

#### Explanation

1. `filter(A2:A, len(A2:A))` prepares the list of words, omitting blanks.
2. "\b" enforce word boundaries, while "e?s?" allows plural forms.
3. `regexmatch` returns True or False, depending on whether the comment in F2 matches.
4. `n` converts True to 1 and False to 0.
5. `sum(arrayformula(...))` says: do the above for each word, and add the results.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you so much! And thank you for the details, that will help me next time @soup